# android - heap size error

Tags: android, eclipse

I developed an Android game using eclipse, i have many resources and images in it, using sdp size unit for sizing the images and to look fine in all devices:

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Also Picasso Library to Load the images on imageviews,

the main problem is that in some devices i get Out Of Heap size memory Error.

question is that, does i have to declare different images with different sizes in subfolders for ldpi, mdpi and so... even if i am using Sdp and Picasso?

Answer (score 0):

Android when loading large background or a lot of pictures, often leading to memory overflow (Out of Memory Error), Based on the experience I have dealt with these issues and other developer experience, finishing solution is as follows (parts of the code and the text source can not be verified) :

Option One, calling attention to the method of reading the image, the appropriate compression
Try not to use or setImageResource setImageBitmap BitmapFactory.decodeResource or set a large image, because these functions after the completion of decode, ultimately by createBitmap java layer to complete, need to consume more memory.
Instead, use the first method by BitmapFactory.decodeStream, create a bitmap, then set it ImageView the source, decodeStream biggest secret lies in its direct call JNI >> nativeDecodeAsset () to complete decode, no longer need to use createBitmap java layer , thus saving space java layer.

```
    InputStream is = this.getResources () openRawResource (R.drawable.pic1).;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    options.inSampleSize = 10; // width, hight to a tenth of the original

    Bitmap btp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (is, null, options);
```

If we add Config parameter image when reading, it can effectively reduce the load with memory, thereby effectively preventing with throwing out of Memory exception.

/ **

```
 * In most provinces memory reads local resources image

 * @param Context

 * @param ResId

 * @return

 * /

public static Bitmap readBitMap (Context context, int resId) {

    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options ();

    opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

    opt.inPurgeable = true;

    opt.inInputShareable = true;

    // Get the resource image

    . InputStream is = context.getResources () openRawResource (resId);

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream (is, null, opt);

    }
```

In addition, decodeStream take pictures directly read the bytecode, not to automatically adapt according to various resolutions of the machine, then use the decodeStream, need hdpi and mdpi, ldpi configured corresponding image resources, or in the different resolutions the machines are the same size (number of pixels), the displayed size is not right.

Option II, when appropriate and timely recovery of the memory image
Typically Activity or Fragment in onStop / onDestroy pictures when you can release resources:

if (imageView! = null && imageView.getDrawable ()! = null) {

```
  Bitmap oldBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable ()) getBitmap ().;

  imageView.setImageDrawable (null);

  if (oldBitmap! = null) {

        oldBitmap.recycle ();

        oldBitmap = null;

  }
```

}

// Other code.

System.gc ();

Upon release of resources, the need to pay attention to the release of associated Drawable Bitmap or whether there is a reference to other classes. If the normal call, you can Bitmap.isRecycled () method to determine whether there are marked recovery; and if it is used by the UI thread interface-related code, you need to be careful to avoid possible recycling of resources to be used, or you could throw the system abnormalities:
E / AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not draw recycled bitmaps
And the exception can not be effectively captured and processed.

Option Three, avoid unnecessary when loading the full image
Only need to know the size of the image under the situation, you can not load the image into memory intact.
Image compression using BitmapFactory time, BitmapFactory.Options inJustDecodeBounds after setting to true, then use decodeFile () and other methods, can calculate the size of the picture in the state does not allocate space. Example:

BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options ();

// Set to true inJustDecodeBounds

opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

// Use decodeFile obtained image width and height

BitmapFactory.decodeFile (path, opts);

// Print out the picture width and height

Log.d ( "example", opts.outWidth + "," + opts.outHeight);
(Ps: in fact, the principle of header information read by the image of the basic image information)

Option IV, optimized Dalvik VM heap memory allocation
Heap (HEAP) is a VM memory for the most part, usually allocated dynamically. Heap size is not static, there is usually a distribution mechanism to control its size. For example, the initial HEAP is 4M large, when 4M space is occupied more than 75% of the time, to re-allocate heap is 8M big; when 8M is occupied more than 75% allocated heap is 16M large. Upside down, when the 16M heap use less than 30%, reduce its size 8M big. Reset the heap size, especially in compression, usually related to memory copy, so change the heap size has an adverse effect on efficiency.
Heap Utilization heap utilization. When the actual utilization percentage deviation from this time, the virtual memory heap size to adjust the time in the GC, so the actual occupancy rate to a percentage closer. setTargetHeapUtilization method dalvik.system.VMRuntime class can provide enhanced processing efficiency program heap memory.

private final static float TARGET_HEAP_UTILIZATION = 0.75f;

// When the program can call onCreate

VMRuntime.getRuntime () setTargetHeapUtilization (TARGET_HEAP_UTILIZATION).;

Programme V, custom heap (Heap) memory size
For some Android projects, affect the performance bottleneck is mainly Android own memory management issues, the current mobile phone manufacturers are more stingy RAM for software fluency is very sensitive to the impact on the performance of RAM, in addition to optimized Dalvik VM heap memory foreign assignment, we can also define your own software to force the memory size, we use dalvik.system.VMRuntime class Dalvik provided to set the minimum heap memory, for example:

private final static int CWJ_HEAP_SIZE = 6 * 1024 * 1024;

VMRuntime.getRuntime () setMinimumHeapSize (CWJ_HEAP_SIZE);. // Set the minimum heap memory is 6MB in size.

However, the above method is still a problem, in fact, just change the function setMinimumHeapSize lower limit of the heap, it prevents too frequent heap memory allocation, when setting the minimum heap size exceeds the upper limit (Max Heap Size) while still using the stack limit, for lack of memory no effect.

Finally, tell us about the picture takes up memory algorithm process. android in the base class image processing is Bitmap, by definition, is a bitmap. Memory-intensive algorithms such as: image width * height * Config.
If Config is set to ARGB_8888, then the above Config is 4. A 480 * 320 image memory usage is 480 * 320 * 4 byte.
By default android memory footprint for the process of 16M, as Bitmap he held in addition to java data, the underlying C ++ graphics library will hold a skia SKBitmap objects, it is generally recommended memory for image size should not exceed 8M. This can be adjusted, you can set the parameters when compiling source code.